# Should abort(404); be returned?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5, should `abort(404)` be returned or will it abort and throw an error and stop my method? I have seen both and both seem to work.

```
public function show($id)
{
    try {
        $item = Item::where('id',$id)->firstOrFail();
    }
    catch(ModelNotFoundException $exception)
    {
        return abort(404);
    }
    return view('item.show')->with(compact('item'));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`firstOrFail()` will throw an error if a model is not found. If you want to catch it I would suggest doing it in the global.php

Yo do not need to return the `abort()` as shown in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#http-exceptions)

Comment: This is good to know, thanks! That said, my question is more about the syntax.  I am unclear whether you need to `return abort(404);` or if `abort(404);` is sufficient.

Comment: You do not need to return it.

Answer (score 3):

You can abort 404 or 403 error.http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#http-exceptions

```
abort(404, 'Page Not Found');
```

Comment: 403 is `Forbidden`, not `Page Not Found`

Comment: @limonte it's just a message